# Have a form submit to two possible different controllers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have the following form on a site

```
<% form_tag({ :action => :subid}, :id=>'run_report', :name => 'run_report') do %>
 Beginning Date <%=  date_select("post", "start_date", :start_year => 2010,:order =>    [:month, :day, :year]) %><br />
 End Date <%=  date_select("post", "end_date", :start_year => 2010,:order => [:month, :day, :year]) %><br />
 <%= submit_tag 'Run', :name => "submit", :class => "submit_btn" %>
<% end %>
```

I want to add another button called Generate that is passed the same variables (start_date and end_date) as the form below but calls the action generate instead of run.  Ideally I'd like to do this without having to have two duplicate forms.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. But you can create partial for dry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible with a javascript. In the view you can use `name` attribute or html5 data-attribute as I do below. The main idea is that it's necessary to store somewhere url to proper form action.

```
<% form_tag(:id=>'run_report', :name => 'run_report') do %>

 <%= submit_tag 'Run', :name => "submit", :data-action => "#{url_for(action1)}", :class => "submit_btn" %>
 <%= submit_tag 'Generate', :name => "generate", :data-action => "#{url_for(action2)}", :class => "submit_btn" %>
<% end %>
```

Simple JQuery script (should work but not tested):

```
var $form = $('#run_report);
$('#run_report :submit').click(function() {
  $form.attr('action', $(this).attr('data-action')).addClass('ready').submit();
});

$form.submit(function(e){ 
  if(!$form.hasClass('ready')) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The trick is that while form has not class `ready`, it won't be submitted. And you add this class after setting proper form action.

This works for me when I initialize hidden form fields with values depending on what button was clicked but with the same form action. Though the approach in your case can be the same. Hope this direction will help you.

Answer (score 1):

or you may bind your button onclick action Something like

```
$("#your_button_id").click(function() {
  $.post("second_url", $("#your_form_id").serialize());
  return true;
});
```

Comment: It's pretty simply but in that case it's necessary to hard code second url.